# Pandas merge one large dataframe with a single row

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes (df, df1) and I want to produce df2.

Here is df.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[20, 10], 
        [100, 15], 
        [95, 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Math', 'Eng'])
df
```

Here is df1

```
data1 = [[20, 10, 25, 40]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Geo', 'Env', 'Phy', 'Bio'])
df1
```

The final result needs to be:

```
data2 = [[20, 10, 20, 10, 25, 40], 
        [100, 15, 20, 10, 25, 40], 
        [95, 14, 20, 10, 25, 40]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Math', 'Eng', 'Geo', 'Env', 'Phy', 'Bio'])
df2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `df1` has only one row, `assign` would be a faster option

```
df.assign(**df1.iloc[0])
```

Or you can also do a cross merge

```
df.merge(df1, how='cross')
```

Result

```
   Math  Eng  Geo  Env  Phy  Bio
0    20   10   20   10   25   40
1   100   15   20   10   25   40
2    95   14   20   10   25   40
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single row, convert your `DataFrame` as `Series` and use indexing:

```
df[df1.columns] = df1.squeeze()
print(df)

# Output
   Math  Eng  Geo  Env  Phy  Bio
0    20   10   20   10   25   40
1   100   15   20   10   25   40
2    95   14   20   10   25   40
```